# Map function to a BST in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a datatype of BST as:

```
data tree a = Empty | Node a (tree a) (tree a)
                    deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

I am doing a simple map function to apply each element of a BST.

```
treeMap :: (a -> b) -> tree a -> tree b
treeMap f (Empty) = Empty
treeMap f (Node left right) = Node (treeMap f left) (treeMap f right)
```

However it gives me an error saying that:

```
Constructor `Node' should have 3 arguments, but has been given 2
In the pattern: Node left right
In the definition of `treeMap':
    treeMap f (Node left right)
              = Node (treeMap f left) (treeMap f right)
```

How do I solve this ? (p/s not a homework question, trying to understand implementation of tree in haskell)

Comment: Off topic: note that `f` must be monotonic to preserve the BST invariant.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the node's value:

```
treeMap f (Node a left right) = Node (f a) (treeMap f left) (treeMap f right)
```

You do need to fix your `data` declaration, though.  Data types must start with capital letters:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

And your type signature

```
treeMap :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
```

This is actually a common pattern in Haskell, and it's been given the name `Functor` with the mapping function called `fmap`.  Lists are one of the most common `Functor`s, with `fmap` just being the standard `map`, but many other types are `Functor`s too.  Conceptually, a `Functor` is just a generic container where you can apply a function to each element.  `Maybe` is also a `Functor`, where `fmap f Nothing = Nothing` and `fmap f (Just a) = Just (f a)`.  Additionally, any `Monad` or `Applicative` is also a `Functor` by definition, so if you can use `do` notation with it then you can use `fmap` on it.

For your structure, you could make it an instance of the `Functor` typeclass as

```
instance Functor Tree where
    fmap f Empty = Empty
    fmap f (Node a left right) = Node (f a) (fmap f left) (fmap f right)
```

Which is exactly the same definition as your `treeMap` with a different name.  Additionally, GHC actually has the ability to derive this implementation for you if you give it the `DeriveFunctor` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
                    deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Functor)
```

And that's all you have to do!

Comment: I just figured it out literally like 2 minutes upon posting. Thanks a lot for your advice on naming convention though!